# CakePHP 3.0 - Regular expression validation

Tags: php, regex, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I need to validate an input based on a regular expression.

```
 //Validator
 $validator
            ->notEmpty('sl_no')
            ->add('reg_no', 'validFormat',[
                    'rule' => '/^([ABCD]{2,2}[0-9]{4,4})$/i',
                    'message' => 'Please enter a valid serial number.'
            ]);
```

But I get the following error:

> Method /^([ABCD]{2,2}[0-9]{4,4})$/i does not exist.

Also, there is no mention of regular expressions in [Cake 3.0 validation Documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/validation.html) unlike [Cake 2 Documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/data-validation.html).

Has this been moved or modified?

Comment: A long time after the fact, but just to note that, instead of {2,2} and {4,4}, you can write {2} and {4} to match exactly 2 and 4 characters respectively.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Try this

```
 $validator
        ->notEmpty('sl_no')
        ->add('reg_no', 'validFormat',[
                'rule' => array('custom', '/^([ABCD]{2,2}[0-9]{4,4})$/i'),
                'message' => 'Please enter a valid serial number.'
        ]);
```

Comment: And an explanation why it so. In CakePHP 3.0 you have a `Validator` object that uses as a default provider the sets described in [`Validation` class](http://api.cakephp.org/3.0/class-Cake.Validation.Validation.html).

From that class you're interested in the [`custom()` method](http://api.cakephp.org/3.0/class-Cake.Validation.Validation.html#_custom) which is used to check a field against a REGEX string.

So you need to specify the rule name (`custom`) and the argument (your regex string) inside the value of the `rule` key when you `add()` it.

Comment: Is it possible to integrate this with DefaultPasswordHasher? I.E after it has matched this validator, it is ran through a function?